# New Nav Bug: Number of Items per Page Resets When Switching Tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, pagination

I create a tab to filter for the java tag. I then set the value for number of questions per page to 50, which it displays. Then I switch to the "Home" tab and see that the value there is set to 15. So I change it to 50, thinking that it must be a per tab setting. Then when I go back to my custom "java" tab it is also set to 15.

Apparently switching tabs resets the questions per page setting.

I should probably say that I'm viewing the site using Firefox 41.0.2 on a Windows 7 Professional.

Still an issue with Firefox 42. Error still exists at the time or this edit.

Comment: Repo'd on Chrome 46 with Windows 7 though I can easily confirm it wasn't doing this yesterday. I switched tabs several times yesterday and my page count stayed at 50.

Comment: @Kendra thanks for your comment, it reminded me that I should have put my viewing environment as well.

Comment: I reproduce with FF41/W7Pro for custom tabs only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in `rev 2015.12.17.3996` (meta) and `rev 2015.12.17.3102` (main).

Comment: I'm seeing `rev 2015.12.17.3999` on Meta here, yet I can still reproduce the behavior in question on Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m on Windows 7.

Comment: As an update on my earlier comment, _now_ I'm seeing it as fixed.

Comment: As for me, "Items per page" keeps on resetting, on December 25. Chrome 46.0.2490.86m.

Comment: Reported again [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314778), [here (?)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313672) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314471). Is this a regression?

Comment: This is still not fixed.

Comment: It may have been fixed in December 2015; it is well and truly unfixed in September 2017.  Please refix it!

Answer (score -3):

This now seems to have been fixed. Using Firefox 43.0.

Comment: No it is not fixed. At least not in my browser.

Comment: I can also confirm it's not fixed. Can you perhaps identify what browser/version you're seeing it as fixed on? Because on the latest Chrome I'm very much still seeing this.

Comment: I edited my post with the browser/version.