# New-Nav page size resets when changing list pages or tabs on a new or refreshed page

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, pagination

When loading a question list or refreshing on a question list, changing pages or tabs in the list resets the page size to 15.

After having set the page size back and switching tabs/pages again the page size remains as set until you reload the page again.

All screenshots were taken on Meta, but the bug occurs on both Meta and Main.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a new browser window/tab to Stack Overflow or Meta Stack
   Overflow.
2. Make sure your page size is set to 50. If you have to change this setting, refresh the page before moving on to the next step.

[image]

3. Switch to page 2 of the tab you are on *or* switch the new-nav tab you are on.
4. Note that the page size switches back to 15.

[image]

5. Set the page size back to 50, then switch pages or to a different tab and note the page size now remains at 50. Either of these options works, regardless of what you did in step 3.

Observed on Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m on Windows 7.

As a side note, this *does not* appear to be the case on manual page changes (manually altering the URL) and only happens when clicking the pagination links on the page.

This is also not the case if you middle click or right click > "Open in new tab" on the page selector itself. However, if you forget yourself and click on the page number in this new browser tab, resetting your page size to 15, the size change will affect your other tab(s).

Comment: Repro on Chrome 47.0.2526.80 m (64-bit) on Windows 8.1...

Comment: Keeps on happening on Chrome 46.0.2490.86m

Comment: Repro on Chrome 47.0.2526.106, Windows 7.

Comment: I'm seeing this (or something so similar that it isn't worth trying a new question) on both Mac OS X 10.10.5 with Firefox 38.5.2 ESR (corporate standard requires this) and on Mac OS X 10.11 with Firefox 43.0.1.  I noticed it before Christmas.  It is irksome indeed.

Comment: I see the same behavior on both Firefox & Chrome on Linux. While researching it (and before finding this post), I [also noticed this weird behavior](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313853/per-page-pagination-intermittently-switches-back-to-15) while switching to a higher limit while on the last page of the current limit.

Comment: This is particularly annoying when a question has _just_ gone off the first page list and I want to go look at it, and I know it's there... And then when I get to the second page I see questions 16-30 from page one instead. Jarring and gets in the way. It's made me specifically stop looking at questions past the first page, at least on Meta.

Comment: Still happening 11 Oct 2016 on Firefox

Comment: Still happening 23 Nov 2016 on Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to call this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) since the issue is gone. We killed that flavor of nav, but learned a lot and are bringing the most popular features back from it. We'll make sure the paging issues don't repeat (they shouldn't...the approach is different this time).

Comment: Works for me. Thanks, Nick! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 7):

Can you please fix this?

In the minimized code:
full.en.js?v=65f133f16fbe
line 4539 (chrome "pretty print").

The page size is never set and will therefore be defaulted in setPaging:

```
function D(e) {
    for (var t, n = /(?:[&?])(page(?:size)?)=(\d+)/gi, i = {}; t = n.exec(e); )
        i[t[1].toLowerCase()] = +t[2];
    O.forEach(function(e) {
        e.setPaging(e.getVisible() ? i.page : 1, i.pagesize)
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In a similar question [New Nav Bug: Number of Items per Page Resets When Switching Tabs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309115/1190388), it was mentioned to have been fixed in Dec. 15, but apparently, it hasn't been!

Maybe a commit-squash/merge gone faulty?

Comment: Two things to note: 1) I actually commented on that answer that it was fixed, then posted this the next day as a new bug because 2) it's a _slightly different_ yet related bug. That bug, ever single time the tab was switched it reset the page size. On this one, I've only been able to reproduce it the first time I change the tab on a question list.