# "That's a miss" but I reckon it's a hit and consequently a bug

Tags: bug, new-nav

**Repro Steps:**

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms
2. Click Page 3
3. Now click Bounties (two are available for Winforms right now)

Actual:
You see the "That's a Miss" page

Expected:
To see the 2 active Bounties as you do if you dont click Page 3

The proof in the pudding is the URL you end up on in both Actual and Expected scenarios *is the same*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms?filter=bounties&sort=size

I think the fix is removing the querystring `&page=3` from the Bounty buttons URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winforms?filter=bounties&sort=size&page=3

[image]

Comment: related if not a duplicate? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313853/per-page-pagination-returns-no-results-when-increasing-limit-on-last-page

Comment: @Stijn *really?* I added a screenshot to prove I am not insane :)

Comment: @JeremyThompson I'm not using the new navigation currently (because of some annoyances and bugs), that's why I couldn't reproduce :)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to share the url you have to use the old nav?

Comment: @JeremyThompson You have to disable it in your Preferences (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/247702 ) and wait a bit for caching to expire.

Comment: Working prefs link for the lazy: http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/  :)

Comment: That red circle... it appears to be... *not freehand*! Travesty!

Comment: @ArtOfCode SHUN, SHUUUN THE UNBELIEVER!

Comment: @ArtOfCode Didn't you hear? There's a new program out which generates freehand circles automatically.

Comment: Happens to me consistently with bounties even from "page 1" of a tag- i.e. going to bounties from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r - generally can fix by opening the same URL in a new tab

Comment: @Chris *open the same URL to get it working* - what's next answer bounties hopping on your left foot in a CCW direction?

Comment: didn't mean it as a solution - just validation that the problem existed and that I hope it can be solved ;)

Comment: Lol - pls don't take that seriously I was just joking :)