# Favorite tags: going to another page will reset per page to 15

Tags: bug, new-nav, tag-watching

I have set `30` messages per page. When I click favorite tag it's still `30` for the first page. But as soon as I navigate to another page (clicking <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>Next page</kbd>) it will be reset to `15`.

Using Chrome, Win7 64x.

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate, no words "tag" or "favorite" in linked question as well as different way to reproduce the problem. I never press "Home" myself, always visit SO site using bookmark to my favorite tag (as I am not really able/want to answer anything without `C#` tag) and there is said issue which I would like to have fixed (if possible).

Comment: [This isn't just on tag pages.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312885/new-nav-page-size-resets-when-changing-pages-on-a-new-page) It happens on any question list. (That's probably a more accurate dupe, since mine _is_ about the page size resetting when switching pages.) Either way, I'm 99.5% sure that they're all down to the same issue and fixing one will fix them all. (I could be wrong.)