# New navigation showing fewer questions

Tags: bug, new-nav

When I click on the new navigation tab for Java questions it shows fewer items, happening only on the 1st page, this is because I have some ignored tags, if I move to page 2 it shows 15 elements correctly but if I go back to page 1 it shows again fewer than 15:

Page 1:
[image]

Page 2:
[image]

It also don't respect my ignored tags list when new elements appear and clicking on the notification bar that appears, I mean the 1 new question text:

As you can see, I have the Android tag ignored, but it's still showing up until I reload the page (F5)
[image]

This is probably related to [this bug when upgrading to jQuery 1.12.4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285095/253715)

Comment: is this related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312885/new-nav-page-size-resets-when-changing-list-pages-or-tabs-on-a-new-or-refreshed ?

Comment: @rene probably related, not sure however