# Pagination won't work properly

Tags: discussion, bug, new-nav, pagination

I have video for [this issue](https://www.screencast.com/t/1Xl4qIkEgkM).

On 1st page I have 50 items per page and after hit 2nd page link I have 15 items per page, but I expect to have 50 items.

Comment: ***Flash player?*** The 2000s called, they want their technology back.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you have tag filters that are making items that are there invisible.

Comment: @Gimby Are you talking about `Favorite Tags`?

Comment: well basically the opposite, you can also set tags you don't want to see. Do you have some of those?

Comment: @Gimby No, I definitely don't have that.

Comment: In fact I could have already seen that as the site specifically mentions at the bottom of the page that there are hidden items because of tag filters, and there is no such thing visible in the video. Secondary option: does the 'number of items' selection switch back to 15 when you switch pages? That seems to have been reported before: [New-Nav page size resets when changing list pages or tabs on a new or refreshed page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312885/424903)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I can reproduce with the following workflow:

1. Go to [home](https://stackoverflow.com/)
2. Set posts per page to 50
3. Go to [bounties tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size)
4. 50 posts are shown on page 1
5. Go to page 2 and you are shown 15 posts and the posts per page value has changed to 15