# Stack Overflow cannot remember how many bounties I want to see

Tags: bug, questions, bounty, pagination

When I visit the [questions with bounties list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size) I see usually 50 questions per page. However when I click on page 2 just 30 questions are shown. I call this a bug.

Comment: That paged view is filtered by the [tag] preferences you selected in your profile.  If you do it right then you *never* see 50 questions per page.

Comment: But I can select the 50 again to see 50 results. I do not really get your argument.