# The /questions feed seems to reset number of items to display

Tags: bug, new-nav, pagination

I prefer to display 50 questions at a time. I've set this on the default tags I watch and on the home page. However, it does not save this setting all the time.

It appears to reset when I perform a new search via the filter bar on `/questions`. If I visit this page, everything resets to 15 items.

Can this not be reset, and instead have `/questions` respect the items per page setting we've already selected.

I am using the new-nav

Comment: I'm not sure, based on your description, that this is the same exact issue, but I think [this bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312885/new-nav-page-size-resets-when-changing-pages-on-a-new-page) might at least be related, due to both having to do with the page size resetting. (Not dupe voting as it does appear a different issue, just related.)