# Per Page Setting Doesn't Always Stick

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I like to keep my questions per page at 50, but that setting won't always stick.

I've read this question:

[New Nav Bug: Number of Items per Page Resets When Switching Tabs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309115/719186)

and this one:

[New-Nav page size resets when changing pages on a new page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312885/719186)

so I think I can add another version that reproduces the reset issue using the following steps (I use Chrome):

1. Go to the Stack Overflow home page and if your setting isn't 50, select 50.
2. Click on one of your Stack Overflow Navigation Tabs.
3. Click on any question in the list.
4. Click on the Stack Overflow banner to get back to the home page.
5. Click on your Navigation Tab again, the setting will now be 15, not 50.

Comment: This looks like a [regression](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309115/4639281)

Comment: At the moment, for me, my home page list 50 questions per page.  If I elect to go to 'page 2' at the bottom, it shows me 15 questions.  I've not been looking at page 2 questions since this started happening — a week or two ago.  I contributed an up-vote to another question related to this topic, but the SO staff don't seem to be paying attention to this.  It is frustrating, though.  I also have the problem with my custom nav tab not keeping the setting.  I don't know if using HTTPS Everywhere has anything to do with it.

Comment: I know it's a highly controversial feature-request, but I still would love to have infinite scrolling. Even 50 questions per page can be skimmed quick enough to get sick of clicking "Next" page.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If using HTTPS Everywhere has something to do with it, I'm not sure what- I don't have that enabled, and I created the second post linked in this question. I'm 99.5% sure that this is pretty much solely a result of changing the URL strings to no longer show the page/size queries as they had been. That was a deliberate change, and makes my life a nightmare when trying to check older questions. (Refreshing on page 2 returning me to page 1, for instance.)

Comment: @Kendra: I'm glad to hear it probably isn't HTTPS Everywhere. It was a possible factor, not a definite one.

Comment: Here as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272043/paging-setting-is-not-remembered-on-custom-search-tab

Comment: What a relief that there's greasemonkey.

Comment: Still seeing this...  also with 30, so it's not just 50. If you set it to another value, it will stick as long as you don't go to another page. At which point it reverts to 15, even when you return to page 1 and refresh.

Comment: This one has really been impacting me lately.  I have been working on cleaning up "older" unanswered (and poorly-answered) questions, and each time I look at a question, I have to start my search (or at least find my context) again.  What a terrible waste of time, and a discouragement from looking at anything but the first page of results.

Comment: I am also seeing this problem currently.  Set it to 50, go to another page, and it reverts back to 15 again.  Results in MASSIVE wasted time and effort when sorting through questions for whatever reason.  Using Safari 10.0.3.

Comment: Another disgruntled user here...