# Number of items per page not being saved after changing tabs

Tags: bug, new-nav, pagination

I know this is a duplicate question from this one: [New Nav Bug: Number of Items per Page Resets When Switching Tabs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/new-nav-bug-number-of-items-per-page-resets-when-switching-tabs), but that question was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) although the issue still remains.

So I'm opening a new question to see if someone can fix this issue.

**ISSUE:** Set **50** items per page in **home** tab go to a **custom** tab you may have created/saved - refresh the page -, then return to **home** tab, the items are now restored to **15**.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312885/new-nav-page-size-resets-when-changing-pages-or-tabs-on-a-new-fresh-page It's also happening when switching pages, but does not happen if you switch the page size back without refreshing.

Comment: Ya but between tabs it restores without refreshing

Comment: I can't repo that. As outlined in the question I linked, if I switch tabs, set the page size back to 50 after it's been reset to 15, then switch tabs again my page size now remains at 50. If I _refresh_ before making the second tab switch, _then_ the page size resets again. I literally just spent a good 30 seconds switching tabs without refreshing, and after setting the page size back to 50 once, it has not reset to 15 again.

Comment: yup my bad it needs a refresh to reset. I'm gonna update my question. Thanks @Kendra

Comment: Sounds good- Though it _is_ still a duplicate of the one I linked, which is about the page size resetting for both changing pages and changing tabs.

Comment: @Kendra well both of ours questions are duplicated of the one I linked in my question, and that one was marked as status completed, which is at the moment not fixed.

Comment: Not quite, as the one you linked had the issue happening _every_ tab change, not just the first until a page refresh. The bug is different, though very similar.